# How to make the following C# GroupBy function better?

Tags: c#

I have a `Dictionary` of type `IDictionary<string, Country>`, whose the `Key` is name of a city and the Value is an `Enum` type of `Country`.

Items in this dictionary would look like these: <"Vancouver", Country.Canada>, <"Seattle", Country.US>, <"New York", Country.US> etc.

I need to group all the items in the dictionry by value (i.e. Country). And output strings like this:

"US Cities: Seattle, New York"
"Canada Cities: Vancouver"

Here is what I've written:

```
public void GroupByCountry(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, Country>> dict)
{
    string text = string.Empty;
    var groups = dict.GroupBy(p => p.Value, p => p.Key);
    foreach (var g in groups)
    {
        List<string> citiesInGroup = new List<string>();
        foreach (string city in g)
        {
            citiesInGroup.Add(ext);
        }
        text += string.Format("{0}: {1}\n", Enum.GetName(typeof(Country), g.Key), string.Join("|", citiesInGroup.ToArray()));
    }
    Log.Info(logCategory, string.Format("Result:\n{0}", text));
}
```

This code works. But I am wondering if it can be more concise and elegant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want a [`Lookup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx):

```
Lookup<Country, string> lookup = dict.ToLookup(pair => pair.Value,
                                               pair => pair.Key);
```

It's not clear what you need to do with the result - if it's *just* formatting, you could use `string.Join` with a projection... but I assume you really need to do something more interesting.

Comment: Couldn't you end up with the same `key` for many cities? Or does `ToLookUp` handle that scenario?

Comment: @hunter: Not sure what you mean - but if it's started off with a `Dictionary<string, Country>` then there can only be one pair per city anyway.

Comment: Woohoo, this question got Jon's attention! I will try your suggestion later.

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't it be easier to have the reverse?

`IDictionary<Country, IList<string>>`

Seems to make more sense in the hierarchy of the items stored.

Comment: Yes, it does. But it's been like that when handed over to me. I am not the one who designed it :)

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
from de in dict
group de by de.Value into dg
select String.Join( "\n", dg.Key + ": " +
    String.Join( "|", dg.Select( v => v.Key ) )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

With Jon Skeet's answered, this could be your elegant solution

```
    Lookup<Country,String> lookup = (Lookup<Country,String>) dict.ToLookup(pair => pair.Value,
                                                                           pair => pair.Key);  
foreach (var a in lookup)
    {
       strOutput += string.Format("{0}:{1} ", a.Key, 
                                   string.Join(",", a.Select(s => s)));
    }
```